# Changing --unsafe-perm is ignored

Tags: node.js, npm

I type the following commands:

```
npm config set --unsafe-perm false
sudo npm install
```

node_modules is created and owned by root user. Isn't is supposed to be created by non-root user?
npm - 6.13.4